# FreeSSHd in jenkins and from commandline

Tags: command-line, ssh, jenkins

i have installed fresshd in one of my windows server.now i am connect to the system through putty. It is working fine.
my issue us when i am running from command line

*PuTTY.lnk  -ssh -2 -P 22 username@XXX -pw pswd -m command.txt*

commands given in the command.txt files are not executed it just open the putty console and it is closing.
when Running from Jenkins also same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are connecting to Windows from a Linux machine, or to Linux from a Windows machine. Or Windows to Windows?

**PuTTY.lnk** is not an executable. If you try to run that, it should produce an error `'PuTTY.lnk' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. I am assuming you are running the command from a Windows machine, since you are referring to windows shortcut file (.lnk)

You need to use **PuTTY.exe** + the rest of your command line. Please note that unless it is in your $PATH settings, you would have to provide a full path to the .exe, for example `C:\LocationOfPuttyInstall\putty.exe -ssh -2 -P 22 username@XXX -pw pswd -m command.txt`. For the sake of preventing any other problem, you should also specify a correct full path to the command.txt file.

If you are not sure where your Putty is installed, on the Windows machine, do the following:

- Right click your PuTTY shortcut (the PuTTY.lnk file)
- Look under **"Target"**

That would list your full path to PuTTY.exe executable.
This should resolve your problem.

p.s.
Usually Putty is used to connect from a Windows machine to a Linux machine. From your question, it almost looks like you are trying to connect from a Windows machine to another Windows machine.

You should use **PsExec** windows tool for such purposes:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx